# Managed Object Crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a managed object that has several NSStrings:

```
@interface Establishment :  NSManagedObject  
{
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * description;
```

I am creating an instance of the managed object and assigning the strings to labels, as such:

```
if ([establishmentData.name length]!= 0) {
        estabName.text = establishmentData.name;
    } else {
        estabName.hidden = YES;
    }
    if ([establishmentData.subtitle length]!= 0) {
        estabTitle.text = establishmentData.subtitle;
    } else {
        estabTitle.hidden = YES;
    }
    
    if ([establishmentData.description length]!= 0) {
        estabDescription.text = establishmentData.description;
    } else {
        estabDescription.hidden = YES;
    }
```

In this case, name has a value, but subtitle and description are nil. When it gets to subtitle, it successfully fails the if and hides the text field, but when it gets to description it crashes EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tried simply NSLogging establishmentData.description and it still crashes

Backtrace throws out 62,000 lines of this:

> ## 62851 0x00d3dbbf in _PF_Handler_Public_GetProperty ()
>
> ## 62852 0x00d3f2fb in -[NSManagedObject _descriptionValues] ()
>
> ## 62853 0x00d3d6b5 in -[NSManagedObject description] ()

and ends with

> ## 62854 0x00004b90 in -[DataTable tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]
>
> (self=0x4d48df0, _cmd=0x6d59e3,
> tableView=0x505d200,
> indexPath=0x6111b00) at
> /Users/Com_23/Documents/projects/Est_list/Classes/DataTable.m:330
>
> ## 62855 0x0032e794 in -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:]
>
> ()
>
> ## 62856 0x00324d50 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:]
>
> ()
>
> ## 62857 0x000377f6 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()
>
> ## 62858 0x00f67fe3 in **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION**
>
> ()
>
> ## 62859 0x00f69594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()
>
> ## 62860 0x00ec5cc9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
>
> ## 62861 0x00ec5240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
>
> ## 62862 0x00ec5161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
>
> ## 62863 0x018bb268 in GSEventRunModal ()
>
> ## 62864 0x018bb32d in GSEventRun ()
>
> ## 62865 0x002c742e in UIApplicationMain ()
>
> ## 62866 0x00002958 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffefe4) at
>
> /Users/Com_23/Documents/projects/Est_list/main.m:14

DataTable being my UITableViewController. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Everything looks fine to me.

Comment: See: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled to enable NSZombies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot give a property the name “description”. See:

[Accessing a property in NSManagedObject causes memory spike and crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476881/accessing-a-property-in-nsmanagedobject-causes-memory-spike-and-crash)

Reference (Apple Documentation):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html

> A property describes a single value
>   within an object managed by the Core
>   Data Framework. There are different
>   types of property, each represented by
>   a subclass which encapsulates the
>   specific property behavior—see
>   NSAttributeDescription,
>   NSRelationshipDescription, and
>   NSFetchedPropertyDescription.
>
> Note that a property name cannot be
>   the same as any no-parameter method
>   name of NSObject or NSManagedObject.
>   **For example, you cannot give a
>   property the name "description"**. There
>   are hundreds of methods on NSObject
>   which may conflict with property
>   names—and this list can grow without
>   warning from frameworks or other
>   libraries. You should avoid very
>   general words (like "font”, and
>   “color”) and words or phrases which
>   overlap with Cocoa paradigms (such as
>   “isEditing” and “objectSpecifier”)

Comment: Yup, changing that did it. Can't believe I didn't find that earlier. Thanks!

Comment: I have a ManagedObject property called newThumbnail and would get a bad access crash when accessing that property at different moments in my app. That would be "new" being the reserved word causing Cocoa paradigm issues. Thanks @magma